# Is the "endo-" prefix in "endotherm" inconsistent/opposite to its use in "endothermic reaction"?

Tags: terminology, metabolism, energy-metabolism

It seems to me that the "endo-" in the biology term "endotherm" is opposite to the "endo-" in the chemistry term "endothermic reaction." Is that the case?

As I understand it:

- an **exo**thermic reaction is one that releases energy into the environment
- an **endo**thermic reaction is one that draws energy from its
  environment.

Given that, I would have expected that:

- an <s>**exo**therm</s> "ectotherm" would be an organism that releases energy into its environment (i.e. warm-blooded)
- and  that an "**endo**therm" is one that draws energy from its environment (i.e. cold-blooded)

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endotherm) puts it (emphasis mine):

> An **endotherm** is an organism that maintains its body at a metabolically favorable temperature, largely by the use of heat released by **its internal bodily functions instead of relying almost purely on ambient heat.**

That really does seem to better match the "exo-" prefix.

Is there a real inconsistency here, or do I just understand this incorrectly?

Comment: See the section “Distinction between endothermic and endotherm” on this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothermic_process

Comment: Endothermic = "inside + temp", as in their source of heat is from within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefix "[endo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/endo-#English)" comes from the Greek "endon" meaning "inner". "Therm" comes likewise from the Greek "therme" meaning heat.

Thus Endo = inner, Therm = heat, heat from inside!

The confusion applies in chemistry, not in that someone has it wrong, but that molecular reactions sometimes release heat - this is obviously to the outside so it must be "[exo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exo-)". The Greek opposite of exo is endo, so the converse reaction (absorbing heat) must be endothermic.

Note also that in the case of an endothermic reaction, the heat supplied for the reaction to work comes from within the materials of the reaction, it's just that in the process of the reaction occurring the heat is "used up" so the reaction vessel feels cold. Because the heat is coming from inside the reaction "endo" makes sense here too.

I did my basic chemistry too long ago for me to remember for endothermic reactions if environmental heat is needed for the reaction to proceed, but I suspect that at any temp above 0 K, the answer is generally no; the heat comes from breaking of intra-molecular bonds.

Comment: "Because the heat is coming from inside the reaction "endo" makes sense here too." Bingo, that makes it make sense and consistent, thanks!